# Incomprehensible SQL query result

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using mysql(5.1.71) and has below table.

```
mysql> DESCRIBE test;
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| foo   | varchar(30) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| hoge  | varchar(30) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM test;
+------+------+
| foo  | hoge |
+------+------+
| aaa  | 111  |
| bbb  | xxx  |
+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And I get below result with the query, but why it shows second row?

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM test WHERE foo=''*'' AND hoge=''*'';
+------+------+
| foo  | hoge |
+------+------+
| bbb  | xxx  |
+------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I guess ''*'' is interpreted as multiply of null strings and the query is same as `SELECT * FROM test WHERE foo=0 AND hoge=0;` but I still can't understand.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of MySQL's implicit type casting and it's strategy to prefer returning strange results over throwing an error. Every other DBMS would simply reject your query because you can't multiply to strings (which is what `'' * ''` does)

Comment: OK about ''*'' but why does SELECT * FROM test WHERE foo=0 AND hoge=0; returns second row?

Comment: Because of the `foo = 0` conditioin MySQL implicitly converts the character values to a number. For the first row `111` is a "valid" number and thus the condition that both columns must be zero fails. For the other row both values are silently assumed to be zero and thus the comparison succeeds.